# How to sum(view) in multiple load file in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

i have some problem. i want sum view in two load file.

example data:

```
load data - 1
id name view
1  A    4
2  B    5
3  C    6

load data - 2
id name view
1  A    4
2  B    5
4  D    6
```

i want output :

```
output
id name view
1  A    8
2  B    10
3  C    6
4  D    6
```

my code in pig:

```
inputdata = LOAD '/user/hdfs/tes/part-1' AS (
    id:chararray, 
    nama:chararray, 
    view:int
);


inputdata2 = LOAD '/user/hdfs/tes/part-2' AS (
    id:chararray, 
    nama:chararray, 
    view:int
);

x = UNION inputdata, inputdata2;

dump x;
```

How i sum view 2 load file in example data.?

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working solution using Group By :

```
inputdata = LOAD '/user/hdfs/tes/part-1' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (
    id:chararray, 
    nama:chararray, 
    view:int
);


inputdata2 = LOAD '/user/hdfs/tes/part-2' USING PigStorage(' ') AS (
    id:chararray, 
    nama:chararray, 
    view:int
);

A = UNION inputdata, inputdata2;
B = group A by (id, nama);
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group.id, group.nama, SUM(B.view) AS sum_views;
DUMP C;
```

There are other possibilities.
This link could help you : https://squarecog.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/group-operator-in-apache-pig/

Comment: thanks. your code is success and complete run. and thanks your link reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
inputdata = LOAD 'part-1,part-2' AS (id:chararray, name:chararray, view:int);

group_inputdata = GROUP inputdata
                        BY (id, name) ;

count_data = FOREACH group_inputdata
             GENERATE FLATTEN(group),
                      SUM(inputdata.view);

dump count_data;
```